# Change layer CRS without displacing relative locations with regard to old CRS

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, convert, transform

I have some points with projected CRS EPSG 3003 (Italy) and I'm displaying them in QGIS on a project map with CRS 3003. If I export the same points with projected CRS EPSG 7791 (Italy) and load them in the map I manage to display them in the exact same locations with regard to the project map CRS 3003. I guess this happens because when I export to a different projected CRS QGIS recalculates the X and Y for that new CRS while keeping the points in the same relative locations with regard to the old CRS. Is there a way to get that with postgis?
If I try to get that with postgis, using st_transform, when I load the new points (with EPSG 7791 on a EPSG 3003 map) the appear slightly displaced. My guess is that postgis doesn't know it should transform while keeping relative original positions with regard to EPSG 3003. Is there any way to achieve this with postgis?

Comment: There are at least two different transformations between epsg:3003 and  epsg:7791.  I guess that QGIS and PostGIS are using different transformations. The  more accurate transformation is using a gridshift file. Maybe the gridshift file is missing from the PostGIS installation. Notice that you compare now transformations QGIS forward-QGIS inverse vs. PostGIS forward-QGIS inverse. PostGIS probably can do the inverse transformation right with the formula that it is using but then you must use PostGIS for both directions.